# Qt: How to create a setting window like in GTK

Tags: qt, user-interface

In Qt 4.8 I want to create a window that looks like the following.

[image: example window]

please note that my main concern is the tab-like behaviour of left-side icon+text combination.

The question is what would you recommend me to achieve that look? A QListWidget or a customized QTabWidget?

thanks

Comment: check out [Config Dialog Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/dialogs-configdialog.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qt Creator - which is written in Qt - has a settings page which might just be what you want:

[image: Qt Creator options dialog]

I would look into the source code of that at http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/trees/master

[Edit]
Found the relevant class here:

https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/tree/master/src/plugins/coreplugin/dialogs

It is the class `SettingsDialog`. The GUI is setup in `createGUI`, they are not using an UI file actually.

This class is using a `QListView` on the left-hand side and a `QStackedLayout` with several `QTabWidgets` inside it on the right-hand side

Comment: it is a great idea but I couldn't find it in the source, actually I lost in the source :/

Answer (score 7):

I'd go with a [QListWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) on the left connected to a [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) on the right.
Items in a QListWidget(View) can have icons on their left, selection can be exclusive (single selection) and when clicked emit signals which can change the current widget shown in the QStackedWidget.

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity of this answer.  Top answer is fine too, but it's a bit difficult to sift through the Qt Creator code